# Tuning simplest FM to 93.5MHz

Tags: capacitor, rf, radio

[image: radio]

[FM Crystal Radio](http://solomonsmusic.net/FM_CrystalRadio.html)

**L** -  4 turns #18 copper or silver wire, 12mm inside diameter, tapped at 2.5 turns

**Ant** - 7 inches of #18 bare copper wire

**C1** - 18 pF ceramic capacitor

**C2** - 50 pF air variable capacitor (? for 93.5MHz)

**D** - 1N34 diode or rock crystal

**R** - 150K resistor

1. How to tune [simplest FM](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/217083/simplest-fm-radio-receiver) at 93.5MHz radio station by fixed value of C1 (18pF), C2? (any formula would very helpful so that I can tune to any radio station)
2. Can I use diode 1N4007 instead of 1N34?

Comment: C2 is variable, and you probably don't want to fix it, because it compensates for an unknown L. You can estimate L from its geometry, but you're not going to get an accurate inductance.

Comment: @uint128_t updated the question. L is fixed **4 turns #18 copper** how about fixed c1,c2  and changing the L value?

Comment: If using a different diode, you still need one with low forward voltage, as the germanium 1N34 is - so a Schottky, not a 1N4007. Preferably a signal Schottky, not a power Schottky. OTOH, I spent a few hours on Wednesday trying to get this to work, 5 miles from a 10,000 watt FM station (with 1N34) and it was a frustrating experience - not a peep out of the thing. **And...** L may be fixed, but you have no idea what it actually is, as-wound, since  every one will vary a bit. It's an inexact science at best.

Comment: @editinit handmade inductors are a bit of an art form. The exact diameter, length and width of every turn can have an impact. You can 'make a guess' based on a nominal inductance value computed from turns#, diameter and coil length, but some 'fine tuning' will most always be necessary.

Comment: Agreed. just wanted to know mathematics behind resonating at 93.5MHz. what values can be variables and what can be fixed.

Comment: I would almost expect that he's not really demodulating the FM signal, but that the FM transmitter inadvertantly also amplitude modulates the signal and that he's demodulating that.

Comment: See this post's answer:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/306497/single-station-fm-radio/306535#306535

Answer (score 2):

While the handmade inductor in this project will most definitely vary from any 'nominal' value we can compute (if you have a meter with inductance measuring, that would be very helpful), here are a few calculators/resources which should prove helpful for giving you a 'starting point.'

- [Coil Inductance Calculator](http://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Air-Core-Inductor-Calculator.phtml)
- [RLC/LC network Resonant Frequency Calculator](http://www.calctool.org/CALC/eng/electronics/RLC_circuit)
- [LC Network Antenna Tuners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_tuner#Basic_lumped_circuit_matching_using_the_L_network)

Keep in mind that a 7" copper wire is far from the resonant length for any FM signal(resonant length for a 93.5MHz quarter-wave antenna would be around 32"), so what you're trying to achieve with the inductor, 2 capacirors & 1 resistor is:

- A radio receiver (tuner) to select and decode the station you're listening to;
- An antenna tuner to 'bring down' the impedance of that stubby antenna to a usable value;
- An impedance matching output to drive your headphlnes, or the input of some form of audio amplifier.